# Create/Manage Quiz in Sharepoint

Tags: survey-list

In sharepoint 2010 platform i want to create / add Quiz (not survey) and save the results to a custom list. To give an example i want to create questions of types multiple choice / yes-no questions etc. And after defining this quiz,i'll assign it to xx users with time limit.

Do you have any approach on this,i searched for scorm but it is very old and i guess not enough document on that subject. Any other 3rd party tool or custom development i can integrate will be helpful,thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use InfoPath, part of a solution is highlighted here in this tutorial: [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/infopath/survey-creator).  To me it would have been better if the questions had come from SharePoint lists rather than storing in the InfoPath document.

It doesn't address the timer issue or how to calculate a score, but it may get your wheels turning.

Comment: If you keep an eye on Mike Herrity's blog, it looks like he is getting ready to cover this very topic using a tool called Author Expert.  http://sharepointineducation.com/?p=3371

Comment: Thanks for the link about Mike's. I couldn't find the tool called Author Expert but i'll wait for his posts on this topic. otherway i am starting to write my  own custom code..

Comment: I'd love to hear back about how it goes for you.  Seems like that is something many people could use.  If you happen to blog about it or anything, please post the URL here.  Good luck!

Comment: I wrote my custom code which reads,writes from splists,it is working now,but really not a good experience for me :)

Answer (score 1):

How about some codeplex projects

http://dynaform.codeplex.com/

[SharePoint Learning Kit](http://slk.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 0):

I think it would take a fair amount of coding with custom application pages to get this to work.  The default SharePoint forms do not work the way you want, and you will also need to have much better control over the flow through the screens along with the timing you mentioned.  It would probably be easiest to save the content to SQL Server and post the results in a custom SharePoint list.

Comment: i can use a 3rd party tool as quiz creator or articulate too but they don't allow tracking results through sql or sp list,if i could find a way in that manner,then my development process will be shorter.
as you say,it will take a lot of coding if i start to write a quiz app.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can give a shot to InfoPath web enabled forms here. InfoPath form services will let you easily create and publish InfoPath forms with the logic you mentioned above and further let you save the data in a list/library.
But i am not pretty sure about implementing the time limit requirement.

Answer (score 0):

The SharePoint Learning Kit has been upgraded to be compat. with 2010.  It is a compat. with SCORM (as in hosting SCORM content), however you must use an authoring tool for the content.

http://slk.codeplex.com/

There are a few full featured commercial packages to create SCROM content and it's easy enough to find via Search.  Here is a link to a small compilation of open source products.

http://docs.moodle.org/20/en/Tools_for_creating_SCORM_content#Tools_for_Authoring

This is not the easiest way, but if you are looking for a solution tailored for this type of thing as well portable, it definitely fits the bill.